# Run a autoit script from a google shhet macro

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a soft written in Autoit who compile the data exported has a Excel file from a Google Sheet.
I want, through Google Sheet macro launch my Autoi soft in the macro, is it possible and if yes how?
Thanks for your return.
Eric

Comment: My guess is that you don't speak English.  You might try to ask you question in your own language and use the google translator because currently the question makes no sense to me.